# Show that continuity hypothesis in the exercise cannot be dropped.

Tags: integration, continuity, riemann-integration

"The Exercise"

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, that $f(x)\ge0,\forall x\in[a,b]$ and that $\displaystyle\int_a^b f=0$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

> ***My attempt:***
>
> We can claim that $f$ has Riemann Integral on $[a,b]$ because of assumption >$\displaystyle\int_a^b f=0$;
>
> so it follows... ;
>
> Since $f$ has Riemann Integral on $[a,b]$, $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\dot{P}$ is any tagged partition of $[a,b]$ with $\delta>||\dot P||$ $$\left|S(f;\dot P)-\displaystyle\int_a^b f\right|<\epsilon$$And  $$\left|S(f;\dot P)\right|<\epsilon$$ That is $$S(f;\dot P)=\displaystyle\sum_i f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)=0\quad, \forall i\in\mathbb N\Rightarrow \forall t_i\in[a,b]$$
>
> It is obvious that $(x_{i+1}-x_i)>0$ so $\forall x\in[a,b],\quad f(x)=0$

Why the continuity hypothesis cannot be dropped?I didn't even use it(I think). And if it is, how am I supposed to convince myself (intuitively and logically)?

Comment: In your last line, how did you get the Riemann sum to equal $0$, when before it was only in an $\varepsilon$ neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: Just for intuition, imagine that your function has a value $c$ at some point, but $0$ everywhere. if the function is continuous, $c$ will fade out smoothly and the integral over $[a, b]$ will not be 0. Otherwise, if the function just spikes at that point with a finite value $c$, the integral will still be 0. so discontinuity will allow the function to spike at some points and won't necessarely be $0$ everywhere.

Comment: $$\text{Noctisdark}$$. Thanx for intuitionic answer, I understood.

$$\text{Theo Bendit}$$. After your comment I thought how I can exactly convert this 
 $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\dot{P}$ is any tagged partition of $[a,b]$ with $\delta>||\dot P||$ $$\left|S(f;\dot P)-\displaystyle\int_a^b f\right|<\epsilon$$ 

to the symbolic limit that $$\lim S(f;\dot P)=0$$ and didn't understand that what the "parameter" of limit and of $S(f;\dot P)$ is? And I now think my last claims were unclear.

Can we say $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum_i^n f(t_i)\triangle x$